# Plot highcharts heatmap graph

Tags: php, jquery, highcharts

Below is rest api json output.

```
{
  "data": {
    "AB": [
      {
        "month": "Nov 2016",
        "total_tax": "132"
      },
      {
        "month": "Dec 2016",
        "total_tax": 88
      }
      ],
    "BC": [
      {
        "month": "Nov 2016",
        "total_tax": "132"
      },
      {
        "month": "Dec 2016",
        "total_tax": 76
      }
    ],
    "MB": [
      {
      "month": "Nov 2016",
      "total_tax": "84"
      },
      {
      "month": "Dec 2016",
      "total_tax": 12
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Above response is pass to jquery ajax function to plot highchart heatmap graph.We are trying to parse ajax response data to get the below pattern for heatmap graph.

```
var xaxisCategory = ['AB','BC','MB'];
var yaxisCategory = ['Nov 2016', 'Dec 2016'];
var series = [
  [0, 0, 132], [0, 1, 88],
  [1, 0, 132], [1, 1, 76], 
  [2, 0, 84], [2, 1, 12]
];
```

By using jquery inArray getting distinct x-axis and y-axis category.In series pattern having [x-axis,y-axis,value].In x-axis having 'AB' index is '0',on y-axis 'Nov 2016' index is '0' and values is total_tax is '132'.So how to plot series data.HoW to plot cartesian series data please help.

Comment: You need to parse your json so it fits Highcharts data, categories format - see example http://jsfiddle.net/h8y4d2pb/3/

Comment: Thanks morganfree it is working.But on y-axis values are same Nov 2016 but in json response it is Nov 2016 and Dec 2016 month

Comment: Well, there is a mistake in the if condition - change indices http://jsfiddle.net/h8y4d2pb/38/

Comment: Formatted code tabs

Comment: Its Done.Working good

Answer (score 0):

Try below example

```
var data =  {
                  "data": {
                    "AB": [
                      {
                        "month": "Nov 2016",
                        "total_tax": 132
                      },
                      {
                        "month": "Dec 2016",
                        "total_tax": 88
                      }
                    ],
                    "BC": [
                      {
                        "month": "Nov 2016",
                        "total_tax": 132
                      },
                      {
                        "month": "Dec 2016",
                        "total_tax": 76
                      }
                    ],
                    "MB": [
                      {
                        "month": "Nov 2016",
                        "total_tax": 84
                      },
                      {
                        "month": "Dec 2016",
                        "total_tax": 12
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                };

var parsedata = data.data;
   var xaxisCategory  = Array();
   var yaxisCategory  = Array();
   var series  = Array();

   jQuery.each( parsedata, function( key, value ) {
    xaxisCategory.push(key);
    jQuery.each( value, function( key, value ) {
        yaxisCategory.push(value.month);
      series.push(value.total_tax);
    });
  });
 console.log(xaxisCategory);
 console.log(yaxisCategory);


 var final = Array();
 var i = 0;
 $.each(series, function( index, value ) {

 var item = Array();
 item.push(i);
 if (index % 2 == 0) {
    item.push(0);
  }
  else {
    item.push(1);
  }

  if (index % 2 != 0) {
   i++;
  }
  item.push(value);
  final.push(item);

 });
 console.log(final);
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v2aye2pw/)  see output in console

Comment: Thanks Khushi. This is perfectly working only for two yaxis Category.In json array month element is varying.It will be for 2,3,4 or 5 month data it`s not fixed.So highchart heatmap not ploting perfectly.